# Add border-bottom property css

Tags: css

I am currently applying the following css to a div when I hover my mouse on:

```
border-bottom: 10px solid;
```

The problem is that all the text contained in the div is shifted upwards by 10px. How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**:
It needs to be compatible with IE8+

Comment: Seems to work just fine - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmd2ap60/2/). Can you post your full CSS, or make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set `box-sizing` to `border-box`, as someone mentioned.

The second one is to make a space for border, then put there a border on hover.

```
<div id=a></div>
<div id=b></div>

<style>
    div {height: 100px;}
    #a {background: red; margin: 0 0 10px;}
    #b {background: green}

    #a:hover {margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 10px solid blue}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwng4vg7/

The last one option set transparent border to default state

```
#a {background: red; border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;}
#a:hover {border-color: blue}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwng4vg7/1/

Answer (score 1):

As the answers state `box-sizing: border-box;` would be the answer, but remember that this is still experimental.

> This is an experimental technology Because this technology's
>   specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for
>   the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the
>   syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change
>   in future versions of browsers as the spec changes

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

What you can do is decrease your `padding` with `1px`. This way you actually replace the `padding` pixel with the `border` and looks like there is just an underline appearing.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add this property to the div `box-sizing: border-box`

> The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.Should they include the border-box or just the content-box which is the default value of the width and height properties. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

This works on most browsers (also IE8) http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Here is an example.

```css
div{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  background:#eee;
  padding:12px 24px;
  color:#333;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div:hover{
  border-bottom:10px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add box-sizing: border-box property or
border-bottom 10px solid transparent on normal border-bottom-color: #000 on hover .